# After starting Python application just get loading screen: working with dash

Tags: python, loading, plotly-dash

After starting my phython application I am just getting a loading screen.

There are no errors in browser console.

After starting my application I am getting this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /assets/lhind.css?m=1544705132.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.24.0&m=1554834449 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.24.0&m=1554834449 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_table/bundle.js?v=3.1.11&m=1544478338 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /assets/style.css?m=1548775287.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_html_components/dash_html_components.min.js?v=0.13.2&m=1537544781 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_core_components/dash_core_components.min.js?v=0.41.0&m=1544541847 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_core_components/plotly-1.42.2.min.js?v=0.41.0&m=1541628517 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:28] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.min.js?v=0.24.0&m=1557930650 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:29] "GET /_favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2019 15:22:29] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_core_components/dash_core_components.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This are my imports:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table as dt
import plotly.graph_objs as go
```

My versions:

```
pandas==0.23.3
dash_table==3.1.11
dash==0.32.2
dash_core_components==0.41.0
numpy==1.15.2
dash_html_components==0.13.2
plotly==3.3.0
```

I already tried (searching in the internet):

- dash version: 0.36.0
- internet without a proxy

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code as well? That would be very helpful to try to help figure this out.

Comment: I am afarid not, beacause it is internal code.

Comment: We can't do much to help otherwise. Those packages and imports aren't the cause of the problem.